# How to change the layout and fields disposition of Django's Admin forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a simple model of a `Student` which is registered to the admin through a `admin.ModelAdmin`.

The admin change form of this model looks like this:
[image: Current look]

I'd like to change the layout of this form a little so that a few fields could be in the same line, like so (edited in Paint):
[image]

Is there something I could do without overriding the default templates? And if there isn't, what's the best way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `fields` attribute in `ModelAdmin` like this:

```
@admin.register(Student)
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fields = (
        ('no_student', 'last_name', 'first_name),
        'course',
        'sex',
        'id'
    )
```

Fields grouped in one sub-tuple or sub-list will be shown in one line. You can create more than one groups like this.

Comment: How is it different from Sagar's answer?

Comment: Using `fieldsets` is redundant in that example, you can do it with `fields` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using fieldsets.

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (('no_student', 'last_name', 'first_name), 'course', 'sex', 'ID')
        }),
        ...
)
```

Please note i have wrapped the fields which should be shown in single line  in same tuple.

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets)